# How to define the isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, then

For $R[x]/\langle x-1\rangle \cong R$, we define the map, $\varphi$ : $R[x]\rightarrow R$, defined by $\varphi(f) =f(1)$

For $R[x]/\langle x\rangle \cong R$, we define the map, $\varphi$ : $R[x]\rightarrow R$, defined by $\varphi(f) =f(0)$

I'm going to show that $R[x]/\langle x^2 -x\rangle \cong R$, help me find an isomorphism if it exists.

In the general case, I'm looking for a technique to define the map.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The last example is not correct, so there is no way to define the map.

Comment: If we assume in some ideal $<x^2 ....>$ it is true

Comment: In the last example now, $R$ must have some non-zero element $a$ with $a^2 = 0$ to which $x$ must be sent.

Comment: Also, it is not quite clear how to continue those dots (more elements, or a longer product?)

Comment: ..... It is some thing became true , isom.

Comment: Please use full sentences in your comments.

Comment: I changed the ideal , now how we define the map

Comment: There is still no good reason why there should be an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok, for example 1 and 2 what the method to define the map

Comment: now the quotient ring on the left has at least 4 idempotents (1, 0, x, 1-x) but it is possible that R only has two, preventing an isomorphism.

Comment: @rschwieb And in fact the quotient is isomorphic to $R\times R$, so it will be rare that it is isomorphic to $R$ (though not impossible).

Comment: @Sara:I think define $\phi(f)$ the root of generator of ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an isomorphism might exist for some special rings $R$, but it doesn't in general. If we assume that $R$ is commutative with $1$ (which is sensible, to avoid issues with the definition of the polynomial ring), then by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) we have
$$
R[x]/\langle x^2 - x \rangle \simeq R[x]/\langle x - 1 \rangle \times R[x]/\langle x \rangle \simeq R \times R
$$
because $x - (x - 1) = 1$ implies that $\langle x \rangle + \langle x - 1 \rangle = R$.

For an explicit counterexample, suppose that $R$ is a domain, e.g. $R = \Bbb{Z}$. Then
$$
R[x]/\langle x^2 - x \rangle \not\simeq R
$$
because the images of $x$ and $x - 1$ in the quotient are non-zero and zero-divisors.